# Trigger event when ALL of an element's pixels are transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, alpha

I have a web page with two canvas elements stacked on top of each other. This is the basis for some functionality that lets me "erase" the top canvas to reveal an image loaded into the bottom canvas. The functionality works well.

What I'm trying to do now is trigger an event once the top canvas has been completely "erased" i.e. all of the pixels for the top context are transparent. I've found ways on SO to check a particular pixel's alpha value via getImageData but I'm trying to figure out a way to determine when the very last pixel's alpha value = 0.

I've included my code as well as an unfinished attempt to do this with a for and if loop (but this seems to not be the best approach). Another issue I've discovered is that when I use getImageData a thin grey border appears around two edges of my canvas.

Thanks for any help in advance!

[image]

```js
window.onload = function() {
    //Move speaker image across page
    var speaker = document.getElementById('speaker');
    speaker.onload = MoveElement(speaker, "right", 1000);

    //Create canvases & contexts
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctxB = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    var ctxT = canvas2.getContext('2d');

    //Get waterfall image object
    var waterfall = document.getElementById('waterfall');

    //Set canvas w&h properties
    canvas.width = canvas2.width = .3*waterfall.width;
    canvas.height = canvas2.height = .3*waterfall.height;

    //Populate Bottom canvas with waterfall image
    ctxB.drawImage(waterfall, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //Populate Top canvas with white rectangle
    ctxT.fillStyle = "white";
    ctxT.fillRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);

    //Make Top canvas "erasable"
    canvas2.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;  
        const eraseSize = 125;
        ctxT.clearRect(x-eraseSize/2, y-eraseSize/2, eraseSize, eraseSize);
    })

    //Attempt to trigger an event when all pixels of top canvas have alpha = 0
    var imageDataTop = ctxT.getImageData(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
    console.log(imageDataTop);

    for (var i = 0; i < imageDataTop; i++) {
        if (imageDataTop.data[i] = 0) {
            //
        }

    }
}

function PlayAudio() {
    document.getElementById('boyfriend').play();
}


//Move an element in a given direction a certain distance
function MoveElement(element, direction, totalDistance) {
    //Determine horizontal or vertical direction
    var LeftOrTop = (direction=="left" || direction=="right") ? "left" : "top";
    
    //Set default frame distance
    var frameDistance = 150;

    //Adjust for backwards direction
    if (direction=="left" || direction=="up") {
        totalDistance *= -1;
        frameDistance = -1;
    }
    
    //Get style data object for element
    var elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);

    //Get Left or Top position of element
    var positionValue = elementStyle.getPropertyValue(LeftOrTop).replace("px", "");

    //Apply direction and distance change to element
    var destination = (Number(positionValue) + totalDistance) + "px";

    function MoveFrame() {
        //If element reaches its destination...
        if (elementStyle.getPropertyValue(LeftOrTop) == destination) {
            //...stop the interval motion
            clearInterval(movingFrames);
        }
        //Otherwise, continue the interval movement
        else {
            elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
            positionValue = elementStyle.getPropertyValue(LeftOrTop).replace("px", "");
            element.style[LeftOrTop] = (Number(positionValue) + frameDistance) + "px";
        }
    }
    //Define time interval for movement
    var movingFrames = setInterval(MoveFrame, 500);
}
```

```css
#stack {
    position: relative;
}
#stack canvas {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-top: 150px;
}

#speaker {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;

    animation-duration: 800ms;
    animation-name: fadein;
    animation-iteration-count: 10;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0.25;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0.25;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'entrance/entrance.css' %}">
        <script src="{% static 'entrance/entrance.js' %}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p hidden>
            <img src="{% static 'entrance/Waterfall.jpg' %}" alt="issue here" id="waterfall" />
        </p>
        
        <img src="{% static 'entrance/sound-icon.svg' %}" id="speaker" />
        <p id="test"></p>

        <audio id="boyfriend" source src="{% static 'entrance/02 30 Minute Boyfriend.mp3' %}" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
        <div id="stack" onmouseenter="PlayAudio()">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataimage that you get will be an array which has 4 bytes per point on the canvas the first 3 bytes of which are the RGB colors and the 4th one is the alpha.

If the color is transparent this 4th one will be 0. You will need to go through each time some erasing is done looking at every 4th byte in the array. If you come across one that isn't zero you will know that the erasing isn't complete.

This is quite a useful reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Comment: @A Haworth thank you for your quick reply. I used this technique combined with setInterval to solve my first problem. As for the thin grey border - it appears when I use the setInterval code but disappears if I comment out that specific line of code. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Interesting - is there a reason you don't do it whenever the user has erased some of the top rather than just looking occasionally? I'd suggest for your second problem that you make a workiing snippet that shows the problem and ask a separate question as it is really a different q.

Comment: That's a good idea. I will do that.